# How to insert into an identity column in MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code:

```
SqlCommand writeCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO computers(id)VALUES()", conn.GetConnection());
            writeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The table `computers` contains an `INT idientity(1,1)` column named `id`.

When I run the code, I get a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ')'`.  I've tried to find a solution, but can't find one on the internet.

Comment: Does the table have any other columns? If yes, what should their values be? If not, what purpose is such a table trying to fulfil, when something like a `SEQUENCE` would likely serve the same purpose and better.

Comment: Your question is _"How to insert into an identity column in MS SQL"_ and the answer is simply [`SET IDENTITY_INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Ilyes I'm trying to let the database handle the id, but it just doesn't. I've tried other syntaxes too, but they don't work either.

Answer (score 0):

*If* the table has other columns as well, and you want to populate them with `NULL` or their `DEFAULT` values, then you can use `DEFAULT VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.computers
DEFAULT VALUES;
```

If, however, your table *only* have the one column, then personally using an `IDENTITY` is the wrong choice; a table that just has an `IDENTITY` is clearly being misused. Instead, use a `SEQUENCE`:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.Computers START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

This scales *far* better, and doesn't suffer the likely race conditions you have. Then, when running an `INSERT` (or similar) you would use `NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Computers`.

Answer (score 0):

For an auto-incrementing identity column the database handles the id value unless I missed something in what you are attempting to do.

```
public void DemoInsert(string ComputerName, ref int newIdentifier)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection { ConnectionString = ConnectionString })
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand { Connection = conn })
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO computers (ComputerName) " + 
                              "VALUES (@ComputerName); " + 
                              "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComputerName", ComputerName);

            cn.Open();

            newIdentifier = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar code like your app, think about it simple crud app

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        SqlConnection con;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        DataSet ds;

        void fillGrid()
        {
            con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=schoolDb;Integrated Security=True");
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from ogrenciler",con);
            ds = new DataSet();
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(ds, "students");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["students"];
            con.Close();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fillGrid();
        }

        private void Addbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText="insert into students(StudentId,StudentName,StudentSurname,City) values("+StudentId.Text+",'"+StudentName.Text+"','"+StudentSurname.Text+"','"+City.Text+"')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            fillGrid();        

        }

        private void Updatebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "update Students set ogrenci_ad='"+StudentName.Text+"',StudentName='"+StudentSurname.Text+"',City='"+City.Text+"' where StudentId="+StudentId.Text+"";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            fillGrid();
        }

        private void Deletebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "delete from ogrenciler where ogrenci_no="+StudentId.Text+"";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            fillGrid();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1.) This does not seem to answer OP's question; 2.) please fix the format of the earlier parts of your code; 3.) your code opens your application to sql injection attacks, on the parts where you concatenate your sql statement with user inputs.